# OpenOffice formula hat symbol not centred

Tags: formula, symbols, openoffice.org

I'm in the OpenOffice formula editor and I want to create a perfectly looking hat theta symbol that blows your mind. Unfortunately, the hat is never correctly centred. Here is a picture of it. The way I enter the symbol is:

hat %theta

In fact, it does look right as long as I'm in the formula editor. As soon as I leave the editor, the hat moves a bit to the left. Is there a hack to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming related question and is off-topic for [SO]. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently other people were able to reproduce the same bug. I found out that if you change the font size within the formula editor (when in the editor, go to Format -> Font size), the hat will be nicely centred again. It seems that the bug only applies to a font size of 12pt. You can choose any font size you want and then change the size of the formula object later to fit the formula to your needs.